# Shutdown function not found

Tags: php, error-handling, callback

I registered a method of an object as a shutdown function:

```
class MyClass {
    public function method1() {
        // ...
        register_shutdown_function(array($this, 'method2'));
    }

    public function method2() {
        // ...
    }
}

$o = new MyClass();
$o->method1();
```

When this script finishes I get a PHP warning:

```
Warning: (Registered shutdown functions) Unable to call MyClass::method2() - function does not exist in Unknown on line 0.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This seems to be a [PHP bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62763). It should have been fixed. At least that's what the commit says. What PHP version are you using?

Comment: @Andrew I'm using version 5.5.10

Comment: I don't know what to tell you to be honest. I've tried this myself just now, using 5.6.13, it seems to be working fine. I suppose you could update your php, if that's an option. If no, you could just call it directly, not the prettiest thing in the world, but then again not too many other options.

Comment: @Andrew Do you mean `register_shutdown_function(function() { $this->method2(); })`?

Comment: Yes, it should work, haven't tried it. But I meant outside the class, so I guess you could have `register_shutdown_function($o->method());` when and where you'd wish to have it.

Comment: For anyone coming here, handler `method2` class method must not be private, or you will face error above.